# Improving speed/responsiveness PHP query return encoding

Tags: php, json

I have the following code as part of a larger web application to search for employees and return the required information.  The queries themselves take little to no time to complete and return the result set.  What appears to need some improvement is how I am currently encoding the results into an array for json_encode to return to the front end.  I am out of ideas for how to improve upon the code (hence my question here).  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```php
<?php
require_once("class.employee.php");
$employee = new Employee();
$employeeSearch = $employee->searchEmployees($_REQUEST['q']);
$employeeResults = array();
$row_array['id'] = $_REQUEST['q'];
$row_array['empName'] = $_REQUEST['q'];
$row_array['empBusinessTitle'] = '';
$row_array['empFacility'] = '';
array_push($employeeResults, $row_array);
while ($empInfo = $employeeSearch->fetchObject()) {
    $row_array['id'] = $empInfo->empUserName;
    $row_array['empName'] = ucwords($empInfo->empName);
    $row_array['empBusinessTitle'] = $empInfo->empBusinessTitle;
    $facilityName = $employee->getFacilityIDByAD($empInfo->empUserName);
    $row_array['empFacility'] = isset($facilityName->facilityName) ? $facilityName->facilityName : '';
    array_push($employeeResults, $row_array);
}
$ret['results'] = $employeeResults;
echo json_encode($ret);

Class Employee {
public function searchEmployees($query) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($this->dbDSN, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT empID, CONCAT(empFirstName,' ',empLastName) as empName, empUserName, empBusinessTitle from $this->tblEmployeePeople where CONCAT(empfirstname,' ',emplastName) LIKE CONCAT('%',:query,'%') and empUserName != ''");
        $statement->bindParam(':query', $query);
        $statement->execute();
        $dbh = null;
        return $statement;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

}?>
```

Comment: Doing wildcard searches in databases is almost always the culprit.  How are you currently benchmarking the speed of the script versus the database?

Comment: Right now I am just using newrelic.com to try and find bottlenecks in my apps and as this is an employee search it is getting hit often and repetitively to find an employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions called in the where clause breaks any index you might have on these fields. Here is the worst part of your query from a performance standpoint.

```
CONCAT(empfirstname,' ',emplastName) LIKE CONCAT('%',:query,'%')
```

First, why the need for the second CONCAT?  Just do this

```
 CONCAT(empfirstname,' ',emplastName) LIKE '%:query%'
```

However, would still hit the index breaking penalty for the first Concat function.  Also, why the wildcard Likes?  You probably want an exact equality check.

I would break the passed in request value 'q' down into 2 parts a first and last name, and pass that to the search function.

Try this in the search function:

```
  $nameArray = explode('',$query );
  $firstname = $nameArray[0];
  $lastname  = $nameArray[1];
```

Then change your query to be:

```
  WHERE ( empfirstname LIKE ':firstname' AND emplastname = ':lastname' ) AND empUserName != ''
```

Then add the binding with wildcard like this:

```
   $statement->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname."%");
   $statement->bindValue(':firstname', $lastname."%");
```

Comment: Well the reason for the first concat is due to the PDO I am using it doesn't work if I don't do it that first way. The wildcard is there to ensure the user finds the employee they want by allowing random guesses effectively at the employee's name.  As for breaking up the query because the front end is a single search/return box there isn't a way of doing that.

Comment: Changing the query to     
SELECT empID, CONCAT(empFirstName,' ',empLastName) as empName, empUserName, empBusinessTitle from people where (empfirstname like '%b%' or emplastname like '%b%') and empUserName != ''
results in approx the same time to query and returns the same result set is that a better/worse way of doing it though?

Comment: Ray is explaining why it is better. 
How many records do you have? In small database size you will feel no performance difference, but still he has the correct query.

Comment: Small size, ~1700 records.  So would the 
     where (empfirstname like '%b%' or emplastname like '%b%')
be a better choice than what I currently ran?

Comment: @Brian Above shows how to split up the search box and add wildcard binding to PDO

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would get rid of all the array parameters that you assign one by one. This takes CPU time to add to the array. Seems that you have a bit of complex loops, try to avoid assigning arrays and that many loops for executing into one page.

-------- UPDATE --------

Just try this update:

```
$row_array = array(
            'id' => $REQUEST['q'],
            'empName' => $_REQUEST['q'],
            'empBusinessTitle' => '',
            'empFacility' = ''
            );

while($empInfo = $employeeSearch->fetchObject()) {
    $row_array[] = $empInfo;
}
array_push($employeeResults, $row_array);
```

And then just request the results by their respective key from the array $row_array.
And as Ray already suggested in his post, update the queries. He's right about that.

Comment: I assumed a large part of the slowdown was due to the creation of the json array before encode and echo but wasn't sure how to better go about it.

Comment: The most of the slow down is in the arrays that you assign with each result in the 'while' loop. And the array_push() is just the culmination.

Comment: Yes can this be accomplished a better way?

Comment: @GTodorov If the size doesn't past a few thousand rows this is a good quick and dirty solution, but this might cause quite a headache down the line with more users.  Brian should know if it will ever get larger.

Comment: The only issue I just found is because of the assignment it auto increments the array, while I need to have it flat for my front end to deal with the result set.